How can I access two columns in a gff file and combine them with bash?
I have a gff file, i want to extract the gene id's (column 9) and the strand (+ or -) (column 7) i want to do this in bash but I don't know how to do this. I only want to extract the line that has the feature type Gene in it (column 3).
i tried this:
#!/bin/bash
gff_file="$1"
sequence_id="$2"
gene_ids=$(zcat "$gff_file" | awk -F'\t' -v seq_id="$sequence_id" '$1 == seq_id && $3 == "gene"             {match($9, /ID=([^;]+)/, arr); print arr[1]$7}')
if [ -z "$gene_ids" ]; then
    exit 0
fi
sorted_gene_ids=$(echo "$gene_ids" | sort -nk2 | awk '{print $1}')
echo "$sorted_gene_ids"

my gff-file looks like this:
chr1    v1.0    gene    289 3692    .   -   .   ID=Oeu061231.1;tid=PAC:37727357;id=gOeu061231.1;Name=Oeu061231.1;gene_id=Oeu061231.1
chr1    v1.0    mRNA    289 3692    .   -   .   ID=Oeu061231.1;Parent=Oeu061231.1;Name=Oeu061231.1;gene_id=Oeu061231.1
chr1    v1.0    exon    289 349 .   -   .   ID=Oeu061231.1:exon:1;Parent=Oeu061231.1;Name=Oeu061231.1;gene_id=Oeu061231.1
chr1    v1.0    CDS 289 349 .   -   1   ID=Oeu061231.1:CDS;Parent=Oeu061231.1;Name=Oeu061231.1;gene_id=Oeu061231.1
chr1    v1.0    exon    473 787 .   -   .   ID=Oeu061231.1:exon:2;Parent=Oeu061231.1;Name=Oeu061231.1;gene_id=Oeu061231.1
chr1    v1.0    CDS 473 787 .   -   1   ID=Oeu061231.1:CDS;Parent=Oeu061231.1;Name=Oeu061231.1;gene_id=Oeu061231.1
...
chr2    v1.0    gene    21189213    21190423    .   +   .   ID=Oeu046640.1;tid=PAC:37723918;id=gOeu046640.1;Name=Oeu046640.1;gene_id=Oeu046640.1
chr2    v1.0    mRNA    21189213    21190423    .   +   .   ID=Oeu046640.1;Parent=Oeu046640.1;Name=Oeu046640.1;gene_id=Oeu046640.1
chr2    v1.0    exon    21189213    21189336    .   +   .   ID=Oeu046640.1:exon:1;Parent=Oeu046640.1;Name=Oeu046640.1;gene_id=Oeu046640.1
chr2    v1.0    CDS 21189213    21189336    .   +   0   ID=Oeu046640.1:CDS;Parent=Oeu046640.1;Name=Oeu046640.1;gene_id=Oeu046640.1
chr2    v1.0    exon    21189890    21189977    .   +   .   ID=Oeu046640.1:exon:2;Parent=Oeu046640.1;Name=Oeu046640.1;gene_id=Oeu046640.1
chr2    v1.0    CDS 21189890    21189977    .   +   2   ID=Oeu046640.1:CDS;Parent=Oeu046640.1;Name=Oeu046640.1;gene_id=Oeu046640.1
chr2    v1.0    exon    21190084    21190150    .   +   .   ID=Oeu046640.1:exon:3;Parent=Oeu046640.1;Name=Oeu046640.1;gene_id=Oeu046640.1
chr2    v1.0    CDS 21190084    21190150    .   +   1   ID=Oeu046640.1:CDS;Parent=Oeu046640.1;Name=Oeu046640.1;gene_id=Oeu046640.1
chr2    v1.0    exon    21190370    21190423    .   +   .   ID=Oeu046640.1:exon:4;Parent=Oeu046640.1;Name=Oeu046640.1;gene_id=Oeu046640.1
chr2    v1.0    CDS 21190370    21190423    .   +   0   ID=Oeu046640.1:CDS;Parent=Oeu046640.1;Name=Oeu046640.1;gene_id=Oeu046640.1

gff_file
when I call the .sh file I also want to filter on the chromosome so for example I would use it like this:
gene_id_extracter.sh example.gff.gz "chr2"

i expected the output to look like this:
Oeu046640.1+


you should edit your question and add a  few sample lines of the GFF file (as a block of code) and the result that you want to obtain from it. I mean, how are supposed to know what you're trying to process?

This sounds like what you probably want:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

zgrep "^$2"$'\t' "$1" | awk -F'[\t=]+' '$3 == "gene" { print $NF $7; exit }'


$ ./tst.sh example.gff.gz chr2
Oeu046640.1+

We use zgrep regexp | awk '...' instead of zcat | awk '/regexp/...' or similar for efficiency since the former requires zgrep to read every line of the gzipped file but awk only sees the lines containing chr2 up until the gene line, while the latter requires both zcat and awk to read every line of the gzipped file.

It seems to work for just printing out one gene ID but some chromosomes have two gene id's and then it will not print out all the different gene id's. I know I didn't specify that this is sometimes the case my apologies.

Okay wait I found it thanks! if I just delete ; exit in the awk statement it prints out all the gene id's thank you for the solution!

To extract gene IDs and strands from a GFF file using bash, focusing only on lines with the feature type "gene" in column 3, you can use awk and sort.
#!/bin/bash

# Ensure a GFF file is provided
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <gff_file>"
  exit 1
fi

gff_file="$1"

# Extract gene IDs and strands from the GFF file
gene_ids=$(awk -F'\t' '$3 == "gene" {match($9, /ID=([^;]+)/, arr); print arr[1] $7}' "$gff_file")

# Check if gene_ids is empty
if [ -z "$gene_ids" ]; then
  exit 0
fi

# Sort and print the gene IDs with their strands
sorted_gene_ids=$(echo "$gene_ids" | sort)

echo "$sorted_gene_ids"


